# Assigning return value of a function to a variable

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time understanding why I can't assign a return value from this simple function to the variable `gcd`:

```
def euclidAlgorithm(m, n):
    if n == 0:
        print "n cannot be zero."
        return -1
    r = m % n # Remainder
    if r == 0:
        return n
    else:
        euclidAlgorithm(n, r)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Input values
    m = 54
    n = 36

    print "Input : m = ", m, " n = ", n
    gcd = euclidAlgorithm(m, n)
    if gcd == -1:
        print "Function terminated with an error"
    else:
        print "Output: gcd = ", gcd
```

Instead of getting `gcd` as 18 I get this when I run it:

```
Input : m =  119  n =  4
Output: gcd =  None
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement at the end of your `euclidAlgorithm(m, n)`. Like this:

```
def euclidAlgorithm(m, n):
    if n == 0:
        print "n cannot be zero."
        return -1
    r = m % n #Remainder
    if r == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return euclidAlgorithm(n, r)
```

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to return the result of your recursion.

```
 ...
else:
    return euclidAlgorithm(n, r)
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot `return`:

```
return euclidAlgorithm(n, r)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive case, your function isn't `return`ing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Without return keyword, the function makes a recursive call but there is no return value till the base conditions are reached.

Refer : [How does using a return clause before a recursive function call differ from not using one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043723/how-does-using-a-return-clause-before-a-recursive-function-call-differ-from-not)

Hence, return is important.