# Do not understand why return statement is needed

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

While going over javascript emulating jquery $, I cannot life of me understand why `return` is needed in this scenario.

Here is the code I am looking at

```
   $ = function(selector){ 
          if ( !(this instanceof $) ) {
              return new $(selector);
          }
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector); 

      Array.prototype.push.apply(this,elements);

   };
```

Can someone please explain to me why return new $(selector) works and not just new $(selector)?   When you do a return, are you starting the whole thing over from the beginning with new keyword? I am having a hard time picturing this. Please help.

Sorry, if I didn't make this super clear. My question is what the statement  'return new $(selector) is doing different vs just new $(selector).  When I put a debugger inside of this if statement and put a watcher on `this`, initially `this` is window and when I step through the function, I see that after running through return new $(selector), it goes back to if statement to see if this is instanceof $(since now `this` is pointed to $). How did that happen is my question. Can someone please tell me when doing "return new $(selector)", where this is returning to??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common JavaScript idiom to make sure you're dealing with an instance object and not a class object.

(JavaScript is technically a prototype-based object system, but the class/instance distinction is the most common/recognizable metaphor for describing this relationship.)

The `$ = function (selector) ...` defines how a "class" of objects will behave. By rights every time you called `$(...)` to instantiate a new object, you'd actually need to call `new $(...)` to return a new instance of the class. `$(...)` is not just a function call; in intent, it's a constructor. It defines how new instances of the class will be formed. That little `instanceof` test and `return new $(selector)` is automating the required `new`--something that is incredibly easy to forget, indeed often idiomatic to not use. The guard condition is there so you *don't* have to call `new` manually.

```
$ = function(selector) { 
      if ( !(this instanceof $) ) {
          // if was called naked, without new, auto-new an instance
          return new $(selector);
      }
    // by time execution arrives here, we have guaranteed that we are
    // dealing with an instance of $, not $ itself (i.e. an instance not
    // the class)
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector); 

    // use Array class to make this instance an array-like
    // object holding the selected DOM elements
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this,elements);
  };
```

**Update / Clarification** The `return` inside the guard condition ends the initial `$(...)` call immediately, returning the value of `new $(...)`. This is basically a recursive definition--albeit a trivial case of recursion that only recurses, at maximum, one time. There are two logical cases to consider.

1. If `$(...)` is called, recurse and return value of `new $(...)`. The `return` is necessary because JavaScript functions return `undefined` by default, if no `return` is used. So code must explicitly return the value of `new ...`.
2. If `new $(...)` is called (either directly, or through that trivial one-step recursion from the guard condition), then we're dealing with an instance. Use `document.querySelectorAll` to find the appropriate nodes and `Array.prototype.push` to load them into this instance. No `return` is necessary in this case because of the magic inherent in a `new` function call, which always returns the instance created. So all that's necessary is to load up the instance as desired. It will be automatically returned.

Thus a typical usage goes like this:

1. `$('p.main')` is the original call
2. `$` function checks and finds it's *not* not dealing with an instance, 
   so recurses, calling `new $('p.main')`
3. `$` function in the second, recursive call is now dealing with an instance.
   It loads the DOM nodes into this instance, and implicitly returns using
   the magic special handling of `new`.
4. The new instance is returned to the guard condition of the original call. 
   It must explicitly `return` the value because it was *not* originally called
   with new, so that outer, original call does *not* enjoy the `new` magic 
   autoreturn. It explicitly returns the new
   instance to the original caller.

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking what the key word `new` is doing. I am asking why the need of `return` is needed.

Comment: I made longer post edit in the original post. Can you take a look to see if my question is clear now?

Comment: I've added a much more detailed, blow-by-blow account of how the return is invoked.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate and detail answer. I will go ahead and accept it as an answer but now I am not sure why just doing 'new $(selector)' won't work.  Doing that is also recursive and I wonder what happens then. If we are calling it w/ new keyword which doesn't require for us to expliclity return by new's definition, why do we still need a 'return new $(selector)?

Comment: The original / outer call, which triggers the guard condition, was **not** called with `new`. So it *must* have an explicit return. The inner call gets a `new`, so can depend on instance autoreturn magic. But the outer call was not called with `new`. That's the key point of the guard and the `return`.

Comment: I understand this concept(really understand through simpler example) on why `return` is needed on recursive call (unless stuff gets assign into another variable). However, when I put a debugger and watch the stack, it acts really funny. Have you ever put this through debugger?

Comment: I just ran through it, in Chrome. Worked as described and expected. One caution about debuggers with recursive functions and/or complex logic: very easy to lose context. I find `console.log` (or similar) print calls better at showing different levels of execution and more complex logic.

Comment: I just re ran this with your suggestion(console log everywhere) with both return and absent of return on new $ and result is that I see when return is used, after new $ was invoked and go through the whole thing, it comes back to the recursion caller(where return statement is ) and returns a value. Whereas, if no `return` is used w/ new $, it goes through and gets the value and never returns since by the time it gets back to recursion caller(in this case, just new $ line), it doesn't do anything and just steps through the rest and whatever value it gets or not doesn't matter(undefined return)

Answer (score 1):

This is to avoid the need to do `new $("yourSelector")` everytime when its needed to interact with your method. The line, `this instanceof $`, checks to see if we are inside an instantiated version of the function, rather than just the function itself.

So if `(this instanceof $)` is `false`, we need to instantiate the function, by doing `return new $(selector)`. The return is important, because we are just inside a normal function at the point. This way, no matter which way we now call the `$` function, we will always get an instance back.

Comment: I made more longer edits into my original post. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I think what I am so unsettling about this whole thing is lack of clear official document on this(or I am just not able to find them or I have not studied enough(clearly not).

I found a very good example from below old question and answer.

[How does using a return clause before a recursive function call differ from not using one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043723/how-does-using-a-return-clause-before-a-recursive-function-call-differ-from-not)

It has this example:

```
function loop(x) {
  if (x >= 10) 
    return x;
  loop(x + 1); // the recursive call
}
loop(0);
```

With my naked and untrained eyeys, it looks like when you recurse up, and eventually when x becomes 10, it says to `return x`. Now, I am assuming, this returns to it's caller(which is loop(x + 1) ??). And since there is no return statement, entire thing returns undefined. Is this right??